# If I flip a coin 10 times, what is the probability that I get heads at least twice in a row?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'd like to see a formula for solving a problem like this in general if that's possible. I know a binomial distribution could be used if the question was "what are the odds that I get heads 2 or more times out of 10 tries" but I specifically want to know what the probability is that I get heads 2 or more times **in a row**. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at Bram's answer below, you could write down a recursion relation for the number of sequences of $n$ coin tosses with no two heads in a row, and solve that.

Comment: One can write such an expression ("formula") using matrix notation (probability transition matrix for Markov process).

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Try calculating the odds of *not* getting at least two heads in a row, and subtract that from $1$

Comment: @amWhy While I agree that it is an elementary trick, it is not always trivial to see that it helps to apply it. Pointing in the right direction is exactly what a hint is supposed to do.

Comment: In this case Not A leads to a rather different problem altogether.   So this is a very good hint I think.

Comment: I've thought about that but I'm not totally sure how to approach that problem either. The odds of not getting at least two heads in a row means that every tails is followed by a heads, which seems to be a little more straightforward of a question, but I'm not sure how to combine that with the 10 flips piece.

Comment: @Imran OK, a further HINT: with no two heads in a row, you can 'sprinkle' in a few heads here and there (of course, making sure they don't end up next to each other), with a maximum of $5$ heads. So, see how many ways you can sprinkle in 0,1,2,3,4, or 5 heads.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can solve it, but here's one using dual recursion.

Let $X_k$ be the event *I get two heads in a row from $k$ flips*, and $Y_k$ be the event *I either get two heads in a row, OR my last flip is H from $k$ flips*. You'll see soon why we need $Y_k$.

So, $X_2 = 1/4$ (HH is the only option) and $Y_2=1/2$ (TH or HH).

Now, if we condition on the last flip, we get

$Pr(X_k) = Pr(X_{k-1}|T)Pr(T) + Pr(Y_{k-1}|H)Pr(H)$

and

$Pr(Y_k) = Pr(X_{k-1}|T)Pr(T) + (1)Pr(H)$

You can walk yourself through it: for $X_k$, if the last flip is T then we need the $k-1$ prior to have two heads since the last T doesn't help. If the last flip is H then we're OK if either we have two H in a row in the prior $k-1$, or the $k-1^{th}$ flip is H. That's why we need $Y_k$.

Similarly, for $Y_k$ is the last flip is a T, then the last flip can't be H so we need two H in the prior $k-1$. If the last flip is H, then we're totally good no matter what happens in the previous $k-1$ by definition.

So - using this recursion, you can plug it into your favorite program and get 55/64 as the answer.